# Enter Keyboard Functionality on Grid Cell while using Navigation

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-column

Hi I have started using AG GRID table, I think it comes with good functionality , I wanted to understand how can I implement Cell Keyboard Entered similar to Cell Edit for my custom cell component, What I wanted here is that When end user try to navigate on cells and press Enter button do we have track of this Event Triggered , I wanted to catch Keyboard Enter event but without using cell edit, It is just a cell with values.

Any lead would be of great help on this.
Thank you in advanced.